# ModelState error of JSON serialization behaves differently in ASP.NET Core 2.2 WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, modelstate

I'm developing an application with ASP.NET Core 2.2. The solution contains two API projects. One is for private APIs and another one is for public APIs.

Both projects have code for model validation through a filter.

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errorKey = context.ModelState.Select(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
            var errorMessage = context.ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors).First().ErrorMessage;

            var globalError = new GlobalErrorObject
            {
                Error = string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage) ? $"The request contained at least one invalid parameter: {errorKey}" : errorMessage,
                ErrorCode = HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity
            };

            context.Result = new CustomActionResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(globalError), HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I pass invalid JSON request data to my first API project, it gives me an invalid model state with errors in exception.

[image]

But passing the same invalid JSON to the second project behaves differently.

[image]

Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

Not sure what could be the issue and why the second API project is not throwing an exception or I have missed any configuration.

**Edit-1** I have error handling middleware in both projects

```
public class RequestMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public RequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {                       
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {        
        //preparing errorObject
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorObject));
    }   
}
```

**Edit-2:** Configure method of both projects

Project 1:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    env.ConfigureNLog(_configuration);

    var rateLimitingOptions = _configuration.GetSection("IpRateLimiting");
    if (rateLimitingOptions != null && Convert.ToBoolean(rateLimitingOptions["EnableRateLimiting"]))
    {
        app.UseAppIpRateLimiting();
    }

    app.UseSecurityHeaders();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMultitenancy<Tenants>();

    app.UseResponseCompression();

    app.UseMiddleware(typeof(RequestMiddleware));
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(
        options =>
        {
            // build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version
            foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
            }

            options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });

    //other services
}
```

Project 2:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    env.ConfigureNLog(_configuration);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMultitenancy<Tenants>();

    app.UseResponseCompression();

    app.UseMiddleware(typeof(RequestMiddleware));
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
        c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you have any middlewares, other action filters?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Yes, I have middleware that handle errors. Updated to the question.

Comment: Do you have it in both projects? Please also show us Configure method from startup class

Comment: @RomanMarusyk: Yes , in both projects. There are a lots of other things in the startup file, so cleaning a bit, however, I'm passing middleware in this way `app.UseMiddleware(typeof(RequestMiddleware));`

Comment: Hi @DivyangDesai - have you been able to fix this? I'm in exactly the same position but with netcore3.1

Comment: @Xmindz, nope I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: .AddNewtonsoftJson(jsonOpt => {
                    jsonOpt.SerializerSettings.ApplyDefault();
                    jsonOpt.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = false;
                });

This fixed it for me. Just wanted to let you know! :)